# Gmail to cPanel Webmail via POP Connection

Tags: email, gmail, cpanel, roundcube

Is there any way to get all of my emails from my Gmail account to my Webmail I meant my cPanel email account like Roundcube? I can take from my cPanel Roundcube all of email to my Gmail account via POP connection but I want to take all of my email from my Gmail account to my cPanel email account via POP or other way.

How it's possible? Could anyone please help me here for this? I will appreciate it! Waiting for answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can forward your emails from gmail to your another email account as below:

1. Login to Gmail
2. Open settings.
3. Click on "Forwarding and POP/IMAP"
4. Click on "Add a forwarding Address"
5. Follow the steps and 
   click the option "Forward a copy of incoming mail to ...... and leave a copy on gmail.
   save.

Now your emails will forward to email id that you have mentioned in forwarding.